# ORACLE SQL - Modifying values based on logic of matching values

Tags: sql, oracle

| TRANSACTION_ID | WAREHOUSE | INTERCOMPANY_ID | ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE | CREATED_FROM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 57261018 | CA |  | INCOME |  |
| 57281538 | CA | 57281544 | ASSET | 57261018 |
| 57281544 | WY | 57281538 | INTERCOINCOME |  |

I get the error "Failed with invalid SQL statement." and I am not sure why. What I want to achieve here:

As you can see **ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE** when **INCOME** this would be the main record in this case. However, the value for **WAREHOUSE** column for this record is incorrect, and we want to display the value from the record where **ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = INTERCOINCOME**, which is **"WY"**. So we want to replace **"CA"** with **"WY"** in this case. I assume we can achieve that if we match various values from these columns between each other. This is what I think we can do: When **ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = INCOME** and his **TRANSACTION_ID** matches the value from **CREATED_FROM** when record **ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = ASSET** then match the value from **INTERCOMPANY_ID** with the value **TRANSACTION_ID** when record is **ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = INTERCOINCOME** then take the value from **WAREHOUSE** which is **"WY"** and paste to the record for column **WAREHOUSE** where **ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = INCOME**  in this case. Would you be so kind and help me out with this ?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
    T.id TRANSACTION_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN TL.accountinglinetype = 'INCOME' THEN (
            SELECT
                LOC2.fullname
            FROM
                transaction T2
                LEFT JOIN transactionLine TL2 ON T2.id = TL2.transaction
                LEFT JOIN location LOC2 ON LOC2.id = TL2.location
            WHERE
                T2.id = (
                    SELECT
                        T3.intercoTransaction
                    FROM
                        transaction T3
                        LEFT JOIN transactionLine TL3 ON T3.id = TL3.transaction
                    WHERE
                        TL3.createdFrom = T.id
                        AND TL3.accountinglinetype = 'ASSET'
                )
                AND TL2.accountinglinetype = 'INTERCOINCOME'
        )
        ELSE LOC.fullname
    END AS WAREHOUSE,
    T.intercoTransaction INTERCOMPANY_ID,
    TL.accountinglinetype ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE,
    TL.createdFrom CREATED_FROM
FROM
    transaction T
    LEFT JOIN transactionLine TL ON T.id = TL.transaction
    LEFT JOIN location LOC ON LOC.id = TL.location
```

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. If you're using Oracle, the MySQL and SQLIte are not appropriate.

Comment: Can you get the actual error from Oracle instead of the useless "invalid SQL" message? It will contain more detail about what's wrong with the SQL.

Comment: Sorry, that is all I get. That is why I am asking what is wrong with the statement.

Comment: When you use a correlated subquery, you can only refer to tables one level up. You're trying to access `T.id` from a 2nd-level nested subquery.

Comment: Try using joins instead of correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite got it where to put 'WY' instead of 'CA' to all matchings or just to Type = ASSET or INCOME - so I did all three of them. Your real warehouses are in last 3 columns of the result dataset (INTERCO_WH_ALL, INTERCO_WH_ASSET, INTERCO_WH_INCOME) and you will take the one that meets your expected result.

Sample data and code:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D  a t a :
    tbl (TRANSACTION_ID,    WAREHOUSE,  INTERCOMPANY_ID,    ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE,  CREATED_FROM) AS
        (   Select '57261018',  'CA', Null, 'INCOME', Null From Dual Union All
            Select '57281538',  'CA', '57281544', 'ASSET', '57261018' From Dual Union All
            Select '57281544',  'WY', '57281538', 'INTERCOINCOME', Null From Dual Union All
            --
            Select '57261010',  'CC', Null, 'INCOME', Null From Dual Union All
            Select '57281530',  'CC', '57281540', 'ASSET', '57261010' From Dual Union All
            Select '57281540',  'WZ', '57281530', 'INTERCOINCOME', Null From Dual
        ),
```

Used combination of Case expressions and analytic functions ( Max() Over() ) to group rows by virtual column COMMON_ID.

... cte for groupings

```sql
  interco AS    -- cte to prepare rows for grouping
    ( Select  t.TRANSACTION_ID, t.WAREHOUSE, t.INTERCOMPANY_ID, t.ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE, t.CREATED_FROM,
              Case When t.ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = 'INTERCOINCOME' 
                   Then (Select CREATED_FROM From tbl Where TRANSACTION_ID = t.INTERCOMPANY_ID) 
              Else Max(t.CREATED_FROM) OVER(Partition By Nvl(t.CREATED_FROM, t.TRANSACTION_ID))
              End "COMMON_ID",
              Case When t.ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE = 'INTERCOINCOME' Then t.WAREHOUSE End "INTERCO_WH" 
      From    tbl t
      Order By  t.TRANSACTION_ID
    )
```

M a i n   S Q L :

```sql
SELECT    i.TRANSACTION_ID, i.WAREHOUSE, i.INTERCOMPANY_ID, i.ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE, i.CREATED_FROM,
          i.COMMON_ID,
          Max(i.INTERCO_WH) OVER(Partition By i.COMMON_ID) "INTERCO_WH_ALL",
          Case  When i.ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE IN('INTERCOINCOME', 'ASSET') 
                Then Max(i.INTERCO_WH) OVER(Partition By i.COMMON_ID) 
          End "INTERCO_WH_ASSET",
          Case  When i.ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE IN('INTERCOINCOME', 'INCOME') 
                Then Max(i.INTERCO_WH) OVER(Partition By i.COMMON_ID) 
          End "INTERCO_WH_INCOME"
FROM      interco i
ORDER BY  i.COMMON_ID, i.TRANSACTION_ID
```

... results as:

```sql
/*
TRANSACTION_ID WAREHOUSE INTERCOMPANY_ID ACCOUNT_LINE_ CREATED_FROM COMMON_ID INTERCO_WH_ALL INTERCO_WH_ASSET INTERCO_WH_INCOME
-------------- --------- --------------- ------------- ------------ --------- -------------- ---------------- -----------------
57261010       CC                        INCOME                     57261010 WZ                               WZ
57281530       CC               57281540 ASSET         57261010     57261010 WZ              WZ
57281540       WZ               57281530 INTERCOINCOME              57261010 WZ              WZ               WZ

57261018       CA                        INCOME                     57261018 WY                               WZ
57281538       CA               57281544 ASSET         57261018     57261018 WY              WY
57281544       WY               57281538 INTERCOINCOME              57261018 WY              WY               WZ                */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the table to itself to find the income and the inter-company income for the assets:

```sql
SELECT a.transaction_id,
       COALESCE(ii.warehouse, a.warehouse) AS warehouse,
       a.intercompany_id,
       a.account_line_type,
       a.created_from
FROM   your_data a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_data i
       ON (    a.account_line_type = 'ASSET'
           AND i.account_line_type = 'INCOME'
           AND i.transaction_id = a.created_from )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_data ii
       ON (    a.account_line_type = 'ASSET'
           AND ii.account_line_type = 'INTERCOINCOME'
           AND ii.transaction_id = a.intercompany_id
           AND i.transaction_id IS NOT NULL );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_data (TRANSACTION_ID, WAREHOUSE, INTERCOMPANY_ID, ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE, CREATED_FROM) AS
SELECT 57261018, 'CA', NULL,     'INCOME',        NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 57281538, 'CA', 57281544, 'ASSET',         57261018 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 57281544, 'WY', 57281538, 'INTERCOINCOME', NULL     FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TRANSACTION_ID | WAREHOUSE | INTERCOMPANY_ID | ACCOUNT_LINE_TYPE | CREATED_FROM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 57281538 | WY | 57281544 | ASSET | 57261018 |
| 57281544 | WY | 57281538 | INTERCOINCOME | *null* |
| 57261018 | CA | *null* | INCOME | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dr7Q0Agk)